# Audio output queue on iOS 5

Tags: ios, core-audio, audioqueueservices

Has anyone ever experienced that an audio output queue in iOS 5 is silent even though the queue is running and no errors are returned?

Downloaded a sample code that had the same issue.

Comment: The silencer is obviously off and the device volume is up.

Answer (score 0):

If you fill the Audio Queue output buffers with zero (or any constant, or very small values close to zero), the audio output will be or seem to be silent.